# marshall object to xml and remove xmlns

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using the following code to do unmarshalling:

```
     @Override
public String marshal(Object document) throws JAXBException {

    Class clazz = document.getClass();
    JAXBContext context =
        JAXBContext.newInstance( clazz.getPackage().getName() );
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(document, sw);
    String xml = sw.toString();
    return xml;

}
```

The result is like this :

```
 <IlpQuoteInput  QuoteId="2888284000185" xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
<Common IlpSellerId="0001">
    <Quotation QuotationDt="20130711"/>
    <Product CurrencyCd="E">
etc etc
```

It is all good, but I actually dont want to have the xmlns in the output, what shall I do ?
Thanks
PS I am using latest version of JAXB and java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mappings you have most likely supplied an `@XmlSchema` annotation on a package-info class that looks something like the following:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.abc.com",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

To remove the the namespace qualification from the XML output you can simply remove the metadata you put in to cause it to happen in the first place, assuming that is what you want to do.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html